# How to get rid of grey lock with an orange triangle Firefox self signed certificate

Tags: firefox, ssl, https

I have a self signed certificate which I trusted in Firefox through 'Add exception', but when I request my localhost site (certificate's Common Name is `localhost`), I see a grey lock with orange triangle:

[image]

While in Chrome:

[image]

I read about it at the Mozilla website (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox):

[image]

But I do not have insecure passive content at `https://localhost`, I just output a blank page, nothing more.

How can I see a green lock in Firefox too?

Thanks for the attention.

EDIT: Here is what Firefox says when I click the lock:

[image]

`Connessione non sicura` means `Connection not secure`.

Firefox's console:

[image]

Comment: does the console of firefox say something?

Comment: @Tom No it doesn't. There's no mixed content warning. In fact, as I said, I just output an empty page.

Comment: @Tom I also flushed the browser's cache

Comment: when you click on the lock what does it say ?

Comment: Only `Connection is not secure`, I posted an EDIT inside of my answer look at my edit.

Comment: Can you try get more informations with Firefox Dev edition ? https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13262/nm-security.png

Comment: I posted a screenshot, but there's no additional useful information I can see, only a request to localhost...